# Replace all numbers with three digits or more

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2016

I have a field say "keywords" which contains random strings of numbers and I'd like to clean the field from any string of numbers which has more than 3 digits.

[image]

I have searched and know wildcards are not possible in replace. Any idea how I can go about that?

Comment: please post what would be your desired result

Comment: @MaralG the image of what you have isn't very clear and also it will be easier to understand what you want by adding an actual example of the output you require: 1) Instead of the image add your example input as text that's easier to read, 2) add an example of what you're expecting when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on 2016, you can use **String_Split()** in concert with **Try_Convert()**

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (idproduct int,searchkeywords varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(109070,'stands & cabinets kantec ams300 1010055 43212002 03906786808 7503 ktkams ltk ams 300')

Select A.idproduct
      ,NewString = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select S = Stuff((Select ' ' +Value
               From (Select Value,Seq=Row_Number() over (Order by (select null))
                       From String_Split(A.searchkeywords,' ')
                    ) B1
              Where (try_convert(float,Value) is null)
                 or (try_convert(float,Value) is not null and len(Value)<=3)
              Order by Seq
              For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
            ) B
```

**Returns**

```
idproduct   NewString
109070      stands & cabinets kantec ams300 ktkams ltk ams 300
```

If you are satisfied with the results, you can apply an update like so:

```
Update A Set searchkeywords = B.S
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select S = Stuff((Select ' ' +Value
               From (Select Value,Seq=Row_Number() over (Order by (select null))
                       From String_Split(A.searchkeywords,' ')
                    ) B1
              Where (try_convert(float,Value) is null)
                 or (try_convert(float,Value) is not null and len(Value)<=3)
              Order by Seq
              For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
            ) B
```

Comment: Thanks John for your response. The string_split didn't work the first time but then I change the compatibilitylevel of the Database to 130 and it started working. ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Comment: @MaralG Hope it helped  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start

Say you have a table called "test_test":

```
create table dbo.test_test (thisStuff varchar(100));
```

With a value like this in it:

```
insert into test_test values ('Hello123 this is 12 a test 22983o398r57298298347238');
```

You can do some limited pattern matching with `patindex()`:

```
select substring(thisStuff,
                 1,
                 patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',thisStuff)-1) + 
       substring(thisStuff,
                 patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',thisStuff)+3,
                 len(thisStuff)) 
from test_test
```

Which converts this value:

```
Hello123 this is 12 a test 22983o398r57298298347238
```

Into this value:

```
Hello this is 12 a test 22983o398r57298298347238
```

In update form it would look like this:

```
update test_test set thisStuff =
   substring(thisStuff,
             1,
             patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',thisStuff)-1) + 
   substring(thisStuff,
             patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',thisStuff)+3,
             len(thisStuff));
```

Which, when run over and over, gives you the progressive values:

```
Hello this is 12 a test 83o398r57298298347238
Hello this is 12 a test 83or57298298347238
Hello this is 12 a test 83or98298347238
Hello this is 12 a test 83or98347238
Hello this is 12 a test 83or47238
Hello this is 12 a test 83or38
```

Before erroring out

```
Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2.
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. (Line 35)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I went by John's answer below but I appreciate your time.